# ElasticSearch sum up nested object field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested field and I want to sum up the values of that nested object using script. I can not use aggregation, as this summation is done for range filtering.

My mappings:

```
    {
      "_doc" : {,
        "properties" : {
          "searchPrices" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "price" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "type" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The query I tried:

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "searchPrices",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "script": {
                      "script": """
                        int sum = 0;
                        for (obj in doc['searchPrices.price']) {
                          sum = sum + obj;
                        } 
                        sum >= 200;"""
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "searchPrices.type": "recurringPrice"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that this script is only picking the first nested document irrespective of the fact that there are multiple search prices within a document.

Sample doc:

```
        {
          "id" : "v2",
          "searchPrices" : [
            {
              "price" : 2000,
              "type" : "recurringPrice",
            },
            {
              "price" : 200,
              "type" : "recurringPrice",
              "conditions" : [
                "addon1"
              ]
            },
            {
              "price" : 400,
              "type" : "recurringPrice",
              "conditions" : [
                "addon2"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

So, instead of considering 2600 as the price, it is only considering 2000 as the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, It seems not be possible by painless script.

According to [Help for painless iterate nested fields](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/help-for-painless-iterate-nested-fields/162394/4?u=occidere) document answered by Elastic Team Member, using painless script at query time only can access one nested object at a time.

So, The situation that you suffered - only considering 2000 as the price - was natural.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it was natural after reading more. But could not find a workaround.